Можно ли в одном составном андроид-приложении на Котлин подружить Google Maps и Yandex Mapkit?
Собрал в одном приложении несколько небольших с целью анализа и изучения... Есть "Погода" - для определения местоположения оно использует "libs.play.services.location" от Google. И есть "Трафик" - оно использует "libs.maps.mobile" от Yandex. Если в "build.gradle.kts (Module :app)" в разделе "dependencies" указать обе библиотеки, то запустится только "Погода", использующая сервис от Google. "Трафик" запустится только если библиотеку от Google закомментировать. Опыт программирования 0+.

Очень советую отказаться от использования двух библиотек, сделай все на яндексе, у них есть сайт с документацией и примером использования. Есть те же функции, что и у гугл. А так... дружить их не лучшая затея :/
